# How can I disable Instruments to automatically launch when I Build&Go to my device?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, instruments

I've used instruments for searching for memory leaks. I did that through XCode *Run > Start with performance tool > Leaks*. Then I quit Instruments. And every time I Build&Go, Instruments automatically launches. Although that's cool, when just wanting to test the app, it's not needed.

How can I turn that off?

Answer (score 1):

Apple+Y or just select build and debug from the build menu.
Apple+R or select build and run from the build menu

the default will now revert to that.

Answer (score 1):

Build & Go uses your last "Run Type" as the "Go" part.

If you select the Build menu, you'll notice that there's a "Build and Run" option. Select it once, and then Build & Go will not load Instruments again until you explicitly ask it to do so.

Comment: After that, Build & Go repeats that action.